# From http to https broken layout about js functions

Tags: javascript, http, https, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

in my local web application, when I switch from "http" to "https", I get broken layout on some button/label. I get this problem only on "dialog" elements.
I have a php file that contains:

```
<div id="entryContainer_'.$entry->idEntry.'">
   <button id="updateLabelButton_'.$entry->idEntry.'">Update Label</button>
       <div id="entryLabel_'.$entry->idEntry.'"style="width:auto;">'.$entry->label.'</div>: '.$entry->value.'
</div>
```

and when I click on button, it has to open the dialog element:

```
<div id="dialog-updateLabelForm" title="Update Entry Label">
            <p id="titleDialogForm">Update Label's Value:</p>
            <form>  
                <input type="text" name="updateLabel" id="updateLabel" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
                <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px"/>
            </form>
      </div>
```

I include the javascript file "dialog.js" with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
```

The javascript file "dialog.js" looks as:

```
$(function() {
var dialog, labelForm, idUpdateEntryLabel, updateLabel = $("#updateLabel:input");

function checkLabel () {
    if (checkValue(updateLabel.val(), 1, 100, /^[a-zA-Z0-9][ A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/i)) {
        updateEntryLabelCall(updateLabel.val(), idUpdateEntryLabel);
        dialog.dialog("close");
    }
    return true;
}

dialog = $("#dialog-updateLabelForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": checkLabel,
        Cancel: function() {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        labelForm[0].reset();
    }
});

labelForm = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkLabel();
});

$("button[id^='updateLabelButton_']").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-pencil"},text: false}).click(function() {
    idUpdateEntryLabel = (this.id).split('_')[1];
    updateLabel.val($('#entryLabel_' + idUpdateEntryLabel).text());
    dialog.dialog("open");
});

});
```

When I switch in browser from http to https, I get problem on layout of the button and dialog window.
Why?

Thanks

Comment: check console if any css file is not getting loaded

Comment: I just checked and all css files are loaded

Comment: you have to look for both js and css, i am saying this because this problem will occur only when some js/css is not getting loaded after switching from http to https. also check the content of js/css

Comment: I understood that the order of include <script> matter. There are three <script> in php file related to different javascript files and changing their order some things works and the others no. Why? Is there a way to load the Javascript files togheter?

Comment: I am not talking about order of js files. I am mainly talking about serving the js and css files on HTTPS url's, some time there are some restrictions on https url's. You need to check the each js/css urls in https and see if you are getting proper content in each js/css files